# Chrome | Strange issue with some of my site images

Tags: google-chrome, networking, console

I am using chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Sadenly, today stoped serving some of the images of a web site I am developing. What I have see is the Chrome console, the network tab, where the image that are not loaded are having status (failed) and type "pending".

Note, that these images, are available if I try to open with their own URL.

Here is the screen shot of the console:

[image]

This issue is available only on Chrome, and not for all the images.

This is for example a tag using one of that images:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.dch/wp-content/uploads/Ads/280x100/7047f30d8145b0d8abb47ff5ed07d703.jpg" alt="" title="" width="280" height="100" />
```

In the above link for example, if I copy the image url, and paste it in another tab of the Chrome, the image will be normaly served, with no error codes or any delay.

Also this image may helps:

[image]

Finally problem solved. I have insalled a plugin that cat my images because of Ad keyword.

Comment: where is the code to call these images ? could you please paste it

Comment: This is a simple image with <img tag, no special code.

Comment: please oblige us with the code , and the dir structure please

Comment: @Satya I have paste the code, that using one of the images.

Comment: did it solve? what was the issue?

Comment: I have installed in my browser an ad blocker that filtering the word Ads. I disabled the blocker for my site and it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these links may help you: [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) error in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824552/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-e)

and

[Failed to load resource under Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome)

try and see if it solves