# CSS not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, business-catalyst

The CSS is not loading for this page of the website I am working on: http://www.thesanfordcenter.net/sanford-center. It happens only in Chrome, but is not a caching issue as the same problem is happening in Chrome on another computer and I have cleared all browsing and cache history in my browser.

It does seem to be working correctly in FF and IE. The sub pages on this site, which use a different template seem to be working fine.

I am not sure what it is that is causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have created two 'stylesheet' folder + you haven't set any body tag on all of your css files, check it out please my friend

Comment: could you show the code line where you are importing the style sheets ? Also is only certain styles not appearing or is it all styles ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing css links between the page you referenced and sub-pages, you have a "media" attribute in your link:

Problem:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/css_Sanford.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px" />
```

Working:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/css_Sanford.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Try removing the "media" attribute and it should work fine.

More specifically, it does not appear that "only" is a valid operating for the media attribute. See [this W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp) for details.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do it! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy to help. Edited the answer to reference the W3School page.

Answer (score 22):

In Google Chrome

```
>> goto settings
>> search for cache
>> clear browsing data
>> check cached images and files (the past hour / day)
>> clear browsing data
```

and goto your webpage and press "Ctrl + r"

Hope this solves your issue 
Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

**Make sure that your CSS and HTM/HTML files use the same encoding !**

If your **HTM/HTML** files are encoded as UNICODE, your **stylesheet** has to be as well.

IE and Edge are not fussy : stylesheets are rendered regardless of the encodings.
But Chrome is totally intolerant of unmatched encodings.

I tried every solution/suggestion i could find all over the Internet before i noticed, in my text editor, that i was using different encodings. Once I saved the stylesheets with the same encoding used for the web pages, the problem disappeared.

Comment: I'm surprised that I can't find this behavior documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist:

this is a 404 not found:

http://www.thesanfordcenter.net/CircularContentCarousel/css/demo.css

Comment: I did remove that line. It did not fix it. Thank you for pointing it out though. I need to clean up my code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the path is correct? The developer tools in Chrome show the following error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (ERROR: The file requested could not be found.) http://www.thesanfordcenter.net/CircularContentCarousel/css/demo.css

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be caused because the browser can't load files:

[Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) error in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824552/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-e)

Answer (score 0):

Check your source where you are calling your code.  The 'stylesheets' folder is coded as 'StyleSheets'.  Possibly the case-sensitive is messing it up.

I'm thinking maybe since the expstickybar.css file is rendering correctly and it references the 'stylesheets' folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had used the wrong Content-Type header (`text/plain` instead of `text/css`). The correct header should be `"text/css; charset=utf-8"`. Unfortunately, no error message was displayed in Chrome.