# Parse.com hosting - Failed to load resource 404 error when loading images

Tags: parse-platform, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

My website is using Parse hosting and for one of the images I'm getting the following error in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

All the files uploaded fine and the image loads when I run the code locally on my machine but after upload this image doesn't appear.

The other images on the site all load fine - what reasons would there be for the above error? The image is only 64KB...

Comment: HTTP error 404 occurs when requested resource could not be found on server. Check the inspect element of the page in question and make sure that requested resource exists there. If you're using image URLs as path, make sure that image URLs are not being redirected because of .htaccess. Refer following thread if it could help you .....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824552/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-e

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried with different images again and the problem was solved. Could have been related to deploying the images to parse.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Great to hear that your issue is resolved now.